# Difficulty processing json with ruby

Tags: ruby, json

I have the following json...

```
{
   "NumPages":"17",
   "Page":"1",
   "PageSize":"50",
   "Total":"808",
   "Start":"1",
   "End":"50",
   "FirstPageUri":"/v3/results?PAGE=1",
   "LastPageUri":"/v3/results?PAGE=17",
   "PreviousPageUri":"",
   "NextPageUri":"/v3/results?PAGE=2",
   "User":[
      {
         "RowNumber":"1",
         "UserId":"86938",
         "InternalId":"",
         "CompletionPercentage":"100",
         "DateTimeTaken":"2014-06-18T01:43:25Z",
         "DateTimeLastUpdated":"2014-06-18T01:58:11Z",
         "DateTimeCompleted":"2014-06-18T01:58:11Z",
         "Account":{
            "Id":"655",
            "Name":"Technical Community College"
         },
         "FirstName":"Matthew",
         "LastName":"Knice",
         "EmailAddress":"knice@gmail.com",
         "AssessmentResults":[
            {
               "Title":"Life Factors",
               "Code":"LifeFactors",
               "IsComplete":"1",
               "AttemptNumber":"1",
               "Percent":"58",
               "Readiness":"fail",
               "DateTimeCompleted":"2014-06-18T01:46:00Z"
            },
            {
               "Title":"Learning Styles",
               "Code":"LearnStyles",
               "IsComplete":"0"
            },
            {
               "Title":"Personal Attributes",
               "Code":"PersonalAttributes",
               "IsComplete":"1",
               "AttemptNumber":"1",
               "Percent":"52.08",
               "Readiness":"fail",
               "DateTimeCompleted":"2014-06-18T01:49:00Z"
            },
            {
               "Title":"Technical Competency",
               "Code":"TechComp",
               "IsComplete":"1",
               "AttemptNumber":"1",
               "Percent":"100",
               "Readiness":"pass",
               "DateTimeCompleted":"2014-06-18T01:51:00Z"
            },
            {
               "Title":"Technical Knowledge",
               "Code":"TechKnowledge",
               "IsComplete":"1",
               "AttemptNumber":"1",
               "Percent":"73.44",
               "Readiness":"question",
               "DateTimeCompleted":"2014-06-18T01:58:00Z"
            },
            {
               "Title":"Reading Rate & Recall",
               "Code":"Reading",
               "IsComplete":"0"
            },
            {
               "Title":"Typing Speed & Accuracy",
               "Code":"Typing",
               "IsComplete":"0"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "RowNumber":"2",
         "UserId":"8654723",
         "InternalId":"",
         "CompletionPercentage":"100",
         "DateTimeTaken":"2014-06-13T14:37:59Z",
         "DateTimeLastUpdated":"2014-06-13T15:00:12Z",
         "DateTimeCompleted":"2014-06-13T15:00:12Z",
         "Account":{
            "Id":"655",
            "Name":"Technical Community College"
         },
         "FirstName":"Virginia",
         "LastName":"Bustas",
         "EmailAddress":"bigBusta@students.college.edu",
         "AssessmentResults":[
            {
...
```

I need to start processing where you see "User:" The stuff at the beginning (numpages, page, ect) I want to ignore. Here is the processing script I am working on...

```
require 'csv'
require 'json'

CSV.open("your_csv.csv", "w") do |csv| #open new file for write
  JSON.parse(File.open("sample.json").read).each do |hash| #open json to parse
    csv << hash.values
  end
end
```

Right now this fails with the error:

```
convert.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <main>': undefined method `values' for ["NumPages", "17"]:Array (NoMethodError)
```

I have ran the json through a parser, and it seems to be valid. What is the best way to only process the "User" data?

Comment: "What is the best way to only process the "User" data?" Well, cycling through everything in the JSON is certainly not it. If you just want the "User" data, start by pulling out the "User" data (e.g. `myJson["User"]`).

Comment: Don't supply a fragment of the JSON. Strip everything that isn't essential, but the JSON has to remain valid, otherwise you make it harder for us to help you.

Comment: Yes, @theTinMan makes an important point. The "User" entry value is evidently an array of at least one hash, but the info is cut off in the middle so we can't describe exactly how to access it.

Comment: Here is an extended version of the data http://pastie.org/9394608

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look at the structure of the JSON object being created. Here's a very small subset of your document being parsed, which makes it easier to see and understand:

```
require 'json'

foo = '{"NumPages":17,"User":[{"UserId":12345}]}'

bar = JSON[foo]
# => {"NumPages"=>17, "User"=>[{"UserId"=>12345}]}

bar['User'].first['UserId'] # => 12345
```

`foo` contains the JSON for a hash. `bar` contains the Ruby object created by the JSON parser after it reads `foo`.

`User` is the key pointing to an array of hashes. Because it's an array, you have to specify which of the hashes in the array you want to look at, which is what `bar['User'].first` does.

An alternate way to access that sub-hash is:

```
bar['User'][0]['UserId'] # => 12345
```

If there were multiple hashes inside the array, you could access them by using the appropriate index value. For example, if there are two hashes, and I want the second one:

```
foo = '{"NumPages":17,"User":[{"UserId":12345},{"UserId":12346}]}'

bar = JSON[foo]
# => {"NumPages"=>17, "User"=>[{"UserId"=>12345}, {"UserId"=>12346}]}

bar['User'].first['UserId'] # => 12345
bar['User'][0]['UserId'] # => 12345
bar['User'][1]['UserId'] # => 12346
```

---

> I'm wondering if I am going down the wrong road with the JSON.parse(File.open("sample.json").read).each do |hash|?

Yes, you are. You need to understand what you're doing, and break your code into digestible pieces so they make sense to you. Consider this:

```
require 'csv'
require 'json'

json_object = JSON.parse(File.read("sample.json"))

CSV.open("your_csv.csv", "w") do |csv| #open new file for write

  csv << %w[RowNumber UserID AccountID AccountName FirstName LastName EmailAddress]

  json_object['User'].each do |user_hash|
    puts 'RowNumber: %s' % user_hash['RowNumber']
    puts 'UserID:    %s' % user_hash['UserID']

    account = user_hash['UserID']['Account']
    puts 'Account->Id:   %s' % account['Id']
    puts 'Account->Name: %s' % account['Name']

    puts 'FirstName:    %s' % user_hash['FirstName']
    puts 'LastName:     %s' % user_hash['LastName']
    puts 'EmailAddress: %s' % user_hash['EmailAddress']

    csv << [
      user_hash['RowNumber'],
      user_hash['UserID'],
      account['Id'],
      account['Name'],
      user_hash['FirstName'],
      user_hash['LastName'],
      user_hash['EmailAddress']
    ]
  end
end
```

This reads the JSON file and parses it into a Ruby object immediately. There is no special magic or anything else that happens with the file, it's opened, read, closed, and its content is passed to the JSON parser and assigned to `json_object`.

Once parsed, the CSV file is opened and a header row is written. It could have been written as part of the `open` statement but this is clearer for explaining what's going on.

`json_object` is a hash, so to access the `'User'` data you have to use a normal hash access `json_object['User']`. The value for the `User` key is an array of hashes, so *those* need to be iterated over, which is what `json_object['User'].each` does, passing the hash elements of that array into the block as `user_hash`.

Inside that block it's pretty much the same thing as access the value for `'User'`, each "element" is a key/value pair, except `'Account'` which is an embedded hash.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed post. I'm having trouble applying what you have posted to the JSON.parse method. I'm wondering if I am going down the wrong road with the JSON.parse(File.open("sample.json").read).each do |hash|?

Comment: Thanks for adding more info Tin. That got me where I need to be!

Answer (score 0):

Read the error message. `each` called on a hash is giving you a sequence of arrays with two members (the key and value together). There is no `values` method on an array. And in any case if what you have is a hash there seems little point cycling through it with `each`; if you want the `"User"` entry in the hash, why don't you ask for it up front?

Comment: So...thats my question. I'm not sure how to ask for just the "User" data? I tryed hash.values["User"], but no cigar.

Comment: But did you try `hash = JSON.parse(File.open("sample.json").read; p hash["User"]`? It seems to me you are not being very systematic; you are just guessing wildly and trying several things at once instead of thinking and breaking the problem down.

Answer (score 0):

Just for posterity and context this is the script I ended up using in its entity. I needed to pull from a url, and process the results and move them to a simple CSV. I needed to wite the student id, first name, last name, and the score from each of 4 assessments to the csv.

```
require 'csv'
require 'json'
require 'curb'

c = Curl::Easy.new('myURL/m/v3/results')
c.http_auth_types = :basic
c.username = 'myusername'
c.password = 'mypassword'
c.perform
json_object = JSON.parse(c.body_str)

CSV.open("your_csv.csv", "w") do |csv| #open new file for write
  csv << %w[UserID FirstName LastName LifeFactors PersonalAttributes TechComp TechKnowledge]
  json_object['User'].each do |user_hash|
    csv << [
      user_hash['UserId'],
      user_hash['FirstName'],
      user_hash['LastName'],
      user_hash['AssessmentResults'][0]['Percent'],
      user_hash['AssessmentResults'][2]['Percent'],
      user_hash['AssessmentResults'][3]['Percent'],
      user_hash['AssessmentResults'][4]['Percent']
    ]
  end
end
```